# Deserialize,edit and save JSON file

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, vb.net, json.net

Im using Json.NET and I have the following JSON file. What I want to do is to be able to add new and remove existing "DicomModalities" from the file and save back the result.

```
  {
  "Name": "PACS",
  "StorageDirectory": "new password",
  "StorageCompression": false,
  "MaximumStorageSize": 0,
  "MaximumPatientCount": 0,
  "Plugins": [
    "C:/Orthanc/Plugins/"
  ],
  "PostgreSQL": {
    "EnableIndex": true,
    "EnableStorage": false,
    "Host": "127.0.0.1",
    "Port": 5432,
    "Database": "ort",
    "Username": "postgres",
    "Password": "77"
  },
  "HttpServerEnabled": true,
  "HttpPort": 8042,
  "HttpDescribeErrors": true,
  "HttpCompressionEnabled": true,
  "RegisteredUsers": {
    "ace": "bat67"
  },
  "DicomModalities" : {
    "Mod1" : {
        "AET": "INSTANCE-A",
        "Port": 123,
        "Host": "10.0.0.1",
        "AllowEcho": true,
        "AllowFind": false,
        "AllowMove": false,
        "AllowStore": false
    },

    "Mod2" : {
        "AET": "INSTANCE-B",
        "Port": 123,
        "Host": "10.0.0.1",
        "AllowEcho": true,
        "AllowFind": false,
        "AllowMove": false,
        "AllowStore": false
    }
},
  "DicomAlwaysAllowStore": false,
  "DicomCheckModalityHost": false,
  "DicomScuTimeout": 10,
  "Dictionary": {}
}
```

So far I have been able to create a new "DicomModalities" object and serialize it but can figure out how to add it into the file or delete existing "DicomModalities" objects eg "Mod1", "Mod2"

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim modality As Modality = New Modality()
        modality.AET = "AET"
        modality.Port = 111
        modality.Host = "22.66.77.88"
        modality.AllowEcho = False
        modality.AllowFind = True
        modality.AllowMove = False
        modality.AllowStore = True

        Dim output As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modality)
        MsgBox(output)
    End Sub

    Public Class Modality
        Public Property AET As String
        Public Property Port As Integer
        Public Property Host As String
        Public Property AllowEcho As Boolean
        Public Property AllowFind As Boolean
        Public Property AllowMove As Boolean
        Public Property AllowStore As Boolean
    End Class
```

Anh help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You problem is that the repeating data (Modality) is NOT set with a set of []  around the start and end of repeating data. As a result, each modality will be considered a separate class object, and NOT a repeating set of data. That data from json point of view is not a array of data, but each instance will have to be considered a new and separate object. Adding new nodes is possible, but are you sure that is the correct data format? As it is now you have ==   MyModals.DicomModalities.Mod1 ==  and ==   MyModals.DicomModalities.Mod2  ==

Comment: You want MyModals.DicomModalities.Mods() (an iList/array) of data.

Comment: As @Albert D. Kallal said, using classes, `Mod1` and `Mod2` are considered properties of `DicomModalities`. You'ld have to modify the classes structure to add a new property. If this JSON is not meant to be used to exchange data, but as storage, change `DicomModalities`, so its value is a Dictionary/List/Array of `Modality` classes.

Comment: Problem is that the DicomModalities is NOT surrounded by a set of []. So this is NOT repeating data. To put in this plain English, it would be like create a new table with ONE row. The table name is required, and it really hard to build a system in which you add a whole new table for ONE row of data. If  data included a set of brackets  around that supposed repeating data this would be easy. In Visual studio, add a new class, empty it out, and then go paste special. Choose XML or JSON and VS will then generate the class object for you. You see that Mod1 and Mode2 are considered sperate classes

Comment: I suppose the user wants things this way - but it means you searching the same set of data as the same type but storing that data as separate nodes (classes/tables) in place of what should be repeating data. Just want to make sure that this rodeo clown mess is really what the poster wants before posting a ugly solution.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal yes unfortunately this is the structure I have to follow. I know an array would have been ideal but I have no choice here.

Comment: Basically I want to be able to add/delete/edit classes to DicomModalities. There could be a hundred classes/tables that might need to be added to DicomModalities ie Mod1, Mod2....Modn but they will all contain the same seven properties/fields as shown in the example.

Comment: Right, but since it not a child of a node, then what happens if the name used is PACS or PostgressSQL?. That name is already used. Your design will force you not only to search for a existing node, but you THEN have to test/check if the fields are the same also. You not be editing by rows of data but by adding a table (node). Because there are no [] around the repeating data, then you not only have to search for a match, you THEN have to determine if the structure is the same. This means that no name conflicts can occur with this design. It also means you can't serialize that data into a list

Comment: It also means that each time you add a new row, you are in fact adding a whole new class to the json, and you have to give that class not only a different name, but a different class TYPE. Each new addition will have to be a brand new class (mod1 and mod2 are different classes - not an instance of type Modality. This suggests that you can fill out your class, serialize it into a string, and then modify the existing object by adding the new json data. As a result you can't with ease use serialization here. You have to create the new mod as a separate json string and add it to the  results.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I fully understand your points but this is what I have to deal with.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal you said you had an "ugly solution" for this....can you please share it? Thanks